# How to return estimate and intercept for multiple regression in Math.Net Numerics?

Tags: c#, linear-regression, math.net

```
public static Vector FindBestMRSolution(Matrix x, Vector y)
{
     return MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(x, y);
}
```

[image]

That is my code so far but that function only returns with the coefficients for the multiple regression but my question is how I can get the intercept returned and/or the estimate for the y value with those same inputs?

I also want to be clear that I found code for how to do this with single regression using math.net numerics but I'm only interested in returning those values with multiple regression only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Capture the result in a vector r:

Vector r = MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(x, y);

If you want a constant term (intercept), you have to include a constant column, probably a column of all 1s, in the matrix x. Conventionally, that would be the first column, so the intercept value is the first element of the return vector.

double intercept = r[0];

To compute the estimated y values, multiply the matrix x by the vector r:

Vector estimates = x * r;

Comment: Parts of the Vector declarations that were in angle brackets were removed. Should be Vector LT double  GT  where LT is less than and GT is greater than.